# inputenc Error: Unicode char ^^A (U+0001) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I upgraded from an older Mac with High Sierra to a new Mac with Catalina and installed a fresh TeX Live package with TeXShop. Two of my old TeX files run fine, but the third is stalling even though I copied the exact same preamble to it. Can someone suggest a way to tackle this, or at least where I might search for a solution? Here's my preamble:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{CSTmacros}
```

Comment: To format properly, you should use the code button (the one that looks like `{}`.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for posting the preamble! Your problem is that a spurious control character got inserted into your document somehow. You need to delete it.

Comment: If you have perl, a one-line perl script will do it. If not, you might `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0001}{\textbf{HERE}}` so that the character shows up in the output as **HERE**. Or look for a line number and paste to a site that lets you see Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Also make sure the document is saved in UTF-8, and not in some other encoding.

Comment: Davislor, thank you very much! I rant it with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0001}{\textbf{HERE}} added to the preamble, and it actually ran without errors! The ways of LaTeX are mysterious indeed. I doubt the added line fixed it. Like so many other times, it "fixed itself." I tested the new line by making an intentional error, and it actually told me the error (what a concept!), so I'm making it a permanent element of my preamble.

Comment: PS to Davislor: I strongly suspect you are right about a spurious control character. I'm completely "legal" except for my Greek alphabet, where I use \def\a{\alpha} etc. I know this can cause problems, but all my files are permeated with this and it would take an enormous effort to revise them. I get away with it most of the time, but now and then there's a hickup :)

Comment: What's illegal about `\def\a{\alpha}`?

Comment: @LSpice It’s perfectly legal. The problem—especially if you use `\def` and not `\newcommand`—is that there’s a big risk that another package will define `\a` to mean something else.

Comment: Thanks again, Davislor. I understand. That's what I meant. I guess I'm not using any packages where my definitions are a problem, although I suspect the occasional hickups (like this last one you helped with) are somehow related. I suspect that the first time a file is run, the system checks for *potential* conflicts. If they don't turn out to be fatal, it eventually accepts them. This is only a (possibly naive) conjecture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comments.

Answer (score 1):

As Davislor pointed out, the problem is probably some "spurious characters" in my code. In fact, I do use "illegal" definitions for Greek letters, namely def\a{\alpha} etc., and sometimes they cause a problem which often "heals" itself spontaneously. This happened here again. I ran my file with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0001}{\textbf{HERE}} in the preamble, hoping to find the error, but it actually ran this time. I'm adding the above line to all my preambles because it points out the error when there is one. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Another approach would be to do `DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0001}{\undefined}` Then you'll get an error will be thrown when LaTeX attempts to process the ctrl-A in the file and you can use the error message that comes up to find the specific line with the offending character.

Comment: Thanks, Donald Hosek. I'm not sure of the difference between the two, since {\textbf{HERE}} also gives me the offending line. What's the "ctrl-A in the file" you mention?